# MySQL not getting installed

Tags: mysql

MySQL is not getting installed on my laptop. It is getting stuck on the same page i.e on the MySQL installer .It only shows connector .When I installed it first time it installed successfully but due to some reason I had to delete it but when i downloaded it and installed second time it started to show this page.I installed and uninstalled it several times but still the problem persist .Can anyone please tell me what to do next or how to install it.I have given the link of its screenshot.
[image: MySQL installer screenshot]

Comment: Perform complete uninstall. Remove all related folders from Program Files and ProgramData, remove all related registry keys/folders. Then download standalone installator and execute it.

Comment: Thanks for answering ,I deleted all the files from c drive and every where. And i did this more than 10 times (deleting files and document related to this). There is no file left . but every time i download it it shows this only .

Comment: Have you cleared the registry?

Comment: you mean from that registry editor

Comment: Yes. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB` and others.

Comment: I Found 2 files of MySQL.should i delete it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117194/discussion-between-realguru-and-akina).

Comment: please can anyone help me